# cocos 2dx version 3.15 --no-native argument not recognised

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

I am using cocos2dx version 3.15, python version is 2.7.12, java version is 1.8.

The problem is when i try to create a web only project 
using `cocos new projectName -l js --no-native` command, it gives me this error:

> cocos new: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-native.

Nowhere in the docs have i found that this command is deprecated/removed.

I have searched a lot for this error, but nobody seem to be getting the same error.

What may be the possible reason for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cocos new projectName -l js --no-native
```

Above command is used for cocos studio, as cocos studio is canceled, the command was removed. There is a [PR](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-console/pull/402) for the same.

Comment: Thanks, what is the command for creating a lightweight web only project?

Comment: @AkKiChaudhary I don't have experience on web project so I can't say anything.